# Can the HTTP response header Authorization be managed from the server?

Tags: http

I'm playing with HTTP Basic Authorization.  As we all know, when a client gets a 401 error on requesting a page, the client must collect authorization credentials from the users (typically in the form of a pop-up window).

Subsequent requests for resources under that part of the URL will be accompanied by "Authorization: Basic [hash]" where [hash] is the username/password mashed together and hashed.

What I'm interesting in is getting the client to not send the Authorization header even when requesting a resource that previously asked for it.

Three important questions:

1. Is this possible?
2. If possible, does this violate the HTTP/1.1 standard (I'm unclear that this case is covered by the spec)?
3. What browser support this?

Thanks for your time, Internet.

**UPDATE**: Apparently, this is an [apache FAQ](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/howto/auth.html#logout) and I am SOL.  Still, if you've got thoughts on this question, I'd love to hear about it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible.  The authenticated session lasts until the user shuts the browser window, and the browser will keep on blindly passing the credentials with each request *under the same path*.

Is there any specific reason why you want this functionality?

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I was hoping to dynamically set authentication on a directory as a form of session management.  However, this is not to be.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the user and password in the URL:

```
http://user:password@example.com
```

If you use this syntax, the browser will generate the header for you.